# Node.js on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I wonder if all Heroku addons - that are currently working for Rails - will work for Node.js once the support is there?

And what is the ETA for the launch of Node.js support?

Answer (score 6):

[Node.js is now officially supported on Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js).

Answer (score 2):

Several addons currently require specific ruby gems to be installed so I think Node.js will have its own separate set of addons.

As for launch, to my knowledge there is no ETA yet.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not an addon will work with node is going to specific to the addon itself, probably whether the addon requires a Ruby lib to work.

I'm currently using Loggly, RedisToGo, Mongolab, and RabbitMQ via Addons all with node.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported by CEDAR stack on heroku

All you have to do is put into `.gitignore` node_modules directory and create Procfile eg.

```
web: node web.js
```

This is just a command to startup your application.

Important thing is that you should layout your app as node_module i wrote a blog post about it
http://no-fucking-idea.com/blog/2012/04/23/building-node-dot-js-module-using-npm/
So you can look it up.

url explaining how to deploy is here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs

Have fun!